# Перлобразные регулярки - как подключить?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день.
Как использовать в RAD Studio XE3 перл образные регулярки?
Я только начинаю изучать Delphi, документация по сравнению с PHP очень скудная, поэтому если можно то с примером.
Спасибо.

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=dephi+pcre&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=brZNUY3XLYOk4gSthYC4BQ

Comment: Гуглить я умею, нашел вот это: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.RegularExpressionsCore.TPerlRegEx 
Вопрос в примере использования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самая удобная библиотека для регулярных выражений для делфи, которую я видел, это - [regexpr](http://regexpstudio.com/RU/TRegExpr/Help/About.html), вот только я не испытывал ее на последних версиях делфи. Но на 7 работало сказочно. Но они не совсем "перловые".

Еще посмотрите [здесь](http://delphi.about.com/od/toppicks/tp/delphi-regular-expressions.htm) и [здесь](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html) и попробуйте подобрать себе удобную.

Comment: Спасибо, многочасовые поиски вывели на http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.RegularExpressionsCore.TPerlRegEx но ума не приложу как использовать в коде. Примеров использования (как например в мануалах по php нет).